# N1QL query add hours and minutes

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

I want to add 5 hours and 30 minute in a time in N1QL. How can I do it ?
I have time like `2016-04-03T18:30:00.000Z`  I need to add 5:30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DATE_ADD_STR(expression, n, part)` Date Function. Your query would look similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_ADD_STR(DATE_ADD_STR(old_time, 5, "hour"), 30, "minute") AS new_time, ...
FROM some_bucket
```

Documentation:

> Performs date arithmetic. n and part are used to define an interval or
>   duration, which is then added (or subtracted) to the date string in a
>   supported format, returning the result. Parts:
>
> - "millennium"
> - "century"
> - "decade"
> - "year"
> - "quarter"
> - "month"
> - "week"
> - "day"
> - "hour"
> - "minute"
> - "second"
> - "millisecond"

Source: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html